# How can I find the derivative?

Tags: calculus

How can I find $dy/dx$ of the equation $xy^2 -x^3y = 6$ ?

I thank you in advance!

Comment: **Hint:** Implicit Differentiation.

Comment: Let's abbreviate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to just $y'$.  Then for example the derivative of $x^2y$ is $2xy+x^2y'$ by the familiar product rule.  You can do.something similar with the terms of your expression to get a derivative in terms of $x, y,$ and $y'$, then solve it for $y'$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another comment said, we use implicit differentiation and apply $\frac{d}{dx}$ to both sides of the equation:

$$\frac{d}{dx}[xy^2-x^3y]=\frac{d}{dx}(6)$$

Since derivatives are linear, we can evaluate each piece of the left hand side separately. Both terms will need the product rule, and both will use implicit differentiation when differentiating $y$, and of course the derivative of a constant is 0.

$$\frac{d}{dx}(xy^2)-\frac{d}{dx}(x^3y)=0$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x)y^2+\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)x-\frac{d}{dx}(x^3)y-\frac{d}{dx}(y)x^3=0$$
$$y^2+2yx\frac{dy}{dx}-3x^2y-x^3\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
Once we're here it's just a matter of isolating $\frac{dy}{dx}$.
$$2yx\frac{dy}{dx}-x^3\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2y-y^2$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}(2yx-x^3)=3x^2y-y^2$$
$$\boxed{\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3x^2y-y^2}{2yx-x^3}}$$